# Monitoring usage resources per user in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, resources, users, central-processing-unit

I want to get statistic hourly by used averages resources per user such as cpu and memory. How I can get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar

SAR to the rescue

You can get activity reports with this linux command. I especially like this article showing different usages:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/

Or, per user, you can use sa:

http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/manual/html_chapter/accounting_6.html#SEC20

```
$ sa --user-summary
                                       23       0.13re       0.01cp         0avio      3163k
root                                    9       0.13re       0.01cp         0avio      3588k
ssperandeo                              3       0.00re       0.00cp         0avio      1467k
rabbitmq                               10       0.00re       0.00cp         0avio      1020k
postgres                                1       0.00re       0.00cp         0avio     25856k
```

Comment: Thnx, but I don't see how I can show it **per user**

Comment: Updated to address user-specific queries.

Comment: This command output result for all time (since last reboot)?

Comment: All time. It saves it to a file.

Comment: A lot of thanx!

Comment: Have a problem.From man:
sa summarizes information about previously executed commands as recorded in the acct file.

But what about execute now program? For example, nodes? How can I view information about not complete process?